# Given a quadrilateral with 4 equal areas, prove that it is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, polygons, geometric-construction

I have the next quadrilateral with midpoints E F G H. The source of the problem is my class of geometry, I read the book but I don't find anything related to this.

[image: Quadrilateral]

I found in Google about Varignon's Theorem then I do the following construction:
[image: Construction]

My question is: it is correct to state that quadrilateral ABCD is a parallelogram? I think that is wrong because I don't use the areas of the statement.

Comment: Please edit your query to provide the following info: [1] What is the source of the problem, book/class, contest, internet...?  [2] If from book/class, then there must have been theorems, previously solved problems or worked examples that the book/class explored, leading up to this problem.  These theorems/solved-problems/worked_examples are your **tools**.  Please edit your query describing as best that you can what you think the pertinent tools are. [3] What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  What is your thinking?  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, edit your query.

Comment: I edited my query :)

Comment: +1 to your query, for responding promptly to my request.  Unfortunately, my knowledge of Geometry is inadequate.  However, other mathSE reviewers should have the necessary knowledge.  Hopefully, since you responded, they will be influenced to at least guide you to a solution.

Comment: Hi! Do we know anything about quadrilateral ABCD?

Comment: Hi @P.J. Only that E, F, G, H are midpoints and the areas showed in screenshot 1. The statement says that a construction is missing to know if quadrilateral ABCD is a parallelogram

Comment: first prove that if A1+A4=A2+A3 then AB is parallel to CD and if A4+A3=A1+A2 then AD is parallel to BC. this can be easily done with area of triangle –

Answer (score 1):

Let ABCD be a rhombus and EFGH be the rhombus formed by mid-points of sides.
Any projection of ABCD on an arbitrary plane has its area reduced by a factor $\cos \theta$ where this angle is between their plane normals.

The inner rhombus area is one-fourth the outer among all the possibilities.